# Processing a Dataset on Javascript/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, xml, cordova, dataset

I am receiving a dataset as a response to a .net web service. I want to know if there is a way to parse it and read the data easily with javascript, jquery...withing my phonegap app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely the data returned will be in json format, so you can basically just loop over the json returned via javascript...  Or if you're using some framework, like I use kendo ui mobile for my phonegap app, but you maybe using jquery mobile...

In any case they both have templating built in as well with some examples for how to play with data returned from .net web services...